# Unresolved dependency org.scala-lang:scala3-library_3.0.0:3.0

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-3

I have a scala `3.0.0-RC1` project that I'm trying to upgrade to scala `3.0.0`.
I set the sbt version to `1.5.2` and `scalaVersion := "3.0.0"` but got this error:

```
[warn] Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-lang:scala3-library_3.0.0:3.0.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to remove `sbt-dotty` plugin from your `project/plugins.sbt`.

Comment: To complete the answer: dotty plugin should be removed when using SBT 1.5+ which is needed anyway for Scala 3

Comment: That is literally what I wrote.

Comment: @insane-e I was just giving a bit more details about _why_ this solution applies.